# Use PowerShell to find files where the last modified time is 30 before the current sysdate/time

Tags: powershell

I have files being deposited to a folder 24/7. Certain files must be processed with companion files. This process runs every 4 hours.

We moves files from this collection folder into a processing folder. The problem is that a lot of the times we problem is that there could be a 10 minute lag between the time one file is deposited and the companion file.

Since I'll be fairly sure that all necessary files will be deposited in 30 minutes, I'm trying to create a PowerShell command to only look for files that are older than 30 minutes to process.

The commented out area of the code is where I'm stuck.

```
get-childItem $FolderInstance*.* | foreach {
    $filePath = $_
    (Get-Item $filePath).LastWriteTime 
    ##(Get-Item $filePath).LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -eq (Get-Date -Minute - 30)} |
    Move-Item $filePath -Destination $ProcessingFilePath  
    }
```

Comment: Try this, before the loop: `$CutOff = (GetDate).AddMinutes(-30)`, then the loop would be: `Get-ChildItem $FolderInstance*.* | where { $_.LastWriteTime -le $CutOff } | foreach { ...`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen's comment will work but if you don't want to define an extra variable you could also do `Get-ChildItem $FolderInstance*.* | where { $_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)} `

Comment: @NekoMusume is correct, but I recommend using a cutoff variable so that all entries are selected using the same criteria. It might not matter but some day it might, in particular if you're processing the files inside the loop and that takes time, then each invocation of `GetDate` will get the current date, which is presumably a different one compared to what was used for the previous item.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You should post that as an answer :)